# Java inner class / closure

Tags: java, closures, anonymous-class

So I have the following:

```
Object a = data.getA();
Object b = data.getB();
Object c = data.getC();
// and so on
```

These objects are retrieved from API calls and may be null. I want to put these objects into a List, but only if they are not null.

I could write a bunch of lines: `if(a!=null) {myList.add(a}` and so on.  But I have the feeling that there is a more elegant way that would avoid having to do the null check each time (aside from creating a helper method to do this).

With javascript, for instance, I could create a closure.  Any ideas for Java?

Comment: What is wrong with a small oneliner helper method?

Comment: There nothing really wrong with it.  But I just wanted to see if there was a way to simulate the inline closure type solution (think lambda) you can achieve with dynamic languages..maybe using an inline class.  Also, I can see this being useful if its one-off throw away logic that makes sense to have inline, instead of having a utility method.

Comment: the problem is that while lambda-like constructs exist in Java, they are not nearly as concise as in other languages, and that makes a (possibly private) helper method the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try [Project LambdaJ](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/wiki/LambdajFeatures) in Google Code, it is very mature in the use of closures with Java

Filtering on a condition:

To filter the items of a collection on a given condition is a very common task and using lambdaj can be as easy as in the following example:

```
List<Integer> biggerThan3 = filter(greaterThan(3), asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
```

The condition that defines how to filter the list is expressed as an [hamcrest](http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/) matcher.

Or you can wait for JDK 8 :-)

Answer (score 7):

How about a utility method?

```
public static <T> void addIfNotNull(Collection<T> col, T element){
    if(element != null){
        col.add(element);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure this would work; but my question was asking if there was a way without doing this ("aside from creating a helper method to do this").  But thank you regardless.

Answer (score 0):

```
List list = new ArrayList();

add(data.getA());
add(data.getB());
add(data.getC());

private add(Object o) {
    if (o != null) {
        list.add(o);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you coud use a Maybe concept: http://www.natpryce.com/articles/000776.html